# Adding Bluetooth plugin in Phonegap Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to use Phonegap's Bluetooth plugin for Android. I downloaded the plugins files from [there](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth) and followed these steps:

- Created a package named com.phonegap.plugin.bluetooth
- Copied Bluetooth.java and BluetoothPlugin.java files into this.
- Added `<plugin name="BluetoothPlugin" value="com.phonegap.plugin.bluetooth.BluetoothPlugin"/>` in plugins.xml

After doing this, I am getting an error in BluetoothPlugin.java in this.ctx:

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from LegacyContext to Context".

How can I resolve this? Also in plugins Bluetooth and BluetoothPlugin folders are given, which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the cordova version you are using. For the most recent version I found this one https://github.com/Viras-/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BluetoothPlugin which I am about to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at this plugin:
[phonegap-bluetooth-plugin](https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin)

Tested and it works from version 2.6 to 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Plugin bluetooth chat, 
https://github.com/furini/BlueGap